# hover over lower z-index div

Tags: css, z-index, pointer-events

I've got 2 divs. they're not overlapping but one is on a higher z-index then the other.
I'm trying to apply a
`div li:hover{ }`
to the lower one but it doesn't work.

I tried `pointer-events: none`, but than all my `onClick` events in the higher div don't work.

Anyway to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Really confuse. Can you explain little bit more clarity?

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. Please provide more details and a jsfiddle.

Comment: There is no way to hover over an element that is behind another element. Why not just change the z-index so it is above it?

Comment: I'm sorry, I seem to have written it very weird... The idea was applying a hover to a lower z-index div but if you say it's impossible...

Comment: you can use jquery to accomplish this,First read z-index of every li element then you can compare values of z-index them whichever has lowest z-index you can apply your css to that one.

Comment: Thanks, and sorry again for the mess...

Comment: you have to target lower z-index you can do this its not impossible but for that you would have to use jquery.Give it try let me know after trying if you could not i will help you by providing you code.

Answer (score 0):

you should use

```
ul li:hover
    {

    }
```

because using div li:hover will target all divs those have li in your View.If you have to target elements only based upon  z-index values you can use jquery to accomplish this.

With jquery you can read value of z-index by iterating through your elements then you can check which one has lower z-index and can apply your css to that one.

further you can also you selectors  firstchild,lastchild,nth-child to target specific ones that you want.